# Java C++ without JNI

Tags: java, c++, ipc

My app is written in Java.
There is a C++ library I need to utilize. I don't want to use JNI.

60 times a second, the C++ app needs to send the Java app 10MB of data; and the Java app needs to send the C++ app 10 MB of data.

Both apps are running on the same machine; the OS is either Linux or Mac OS X.

What is the most efficient way to do this? (At the moment, I'm considering TCPIP ports; but in C++, I can do memory mapping -- can I do something similar in Java?)

Thanks!

Comment: You're talking 1.2GB a second of data transfer... are you sure you've got your numbers right here? That's verging on a significant fraction of what server memory bandwidth can sustain.

Comment: yes http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#map%28java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode,%20long,%20long%29

Comment: It's a physics simulator talking to a graphics rendering engine. The numbers are not off.

Comment: The numbers may not be "off", but what I think @skaffman is saying is that such a data transfer rate may be unachievable, and maybe even physically impossible ... given all the other things that have to happen on the machine in addition to the data transfer.

Comment: Have a look at JNA https://github.com/java-native-access/jna

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using mapped files is a way of hand-rolling a highly optimized rpc. You might consider starting with a web service talking over local sockets, using MTOM for attaching the data, or just dropping it into a file. Then you could measure the performance. If the data was a problem, you could then use mapping.

Note that there are some odd restrictions on this that make your code sensitive to whether it is running on Windows or not. On Windows, you can't delete something that is open.

I should point out that I have done exactly what you are proposing here. It has a control channel on a socket, and the data is shared via a file that is mmapped in C++ (or the Windows equivalent) and NIO mapped in Java. It works. I've never measured maximum throughput, though.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, Java has memory-mapped files with the NIO framework.

If you're trying to avoid JNI because you didn't want to write stubs, you can also interface with C++ code (at least ones that are `extern "C"`) using [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/). For best performance, use direct mapping (concrete classes with `native` methods, not a mapped interface)---see documentation for more details. :-)

Comment: JNA is just a wrapper on JNI.

Comment: Yes---I just edited my question to say that if the OP wanted to avoid JNI because of the need to avoid writing stubs, then JNA is a good alternative (as it handles the stubs for you).

Comment: I want to avoid JNI to avoid unstability. I don't trust the C++ library to not have bugs and do not want it to destabilize my Java VM.

Comment: So using Java NIO, the idea is that C++ & Java NIO memory map the same file, then they communicate via this file? With locking done via some external source, like TCP/IP ?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like shared memory would be the way to go.  I believe the NIO libraries support that.

The question is WHAT do you want your program to do?

Answer (score 2):

You should give a look at [BridJ](http://code.google.com/p/bridj/) (and [JNAerator](http://code.google.com/p/jnaerator/)).

It's a recent alternative to JNA with support for C++ and a special focus on performance.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly helpful and will be interesting at least to develop but you could throw in an SSD/RAM drive accessible to both the Java and C++ application and have a sort of juggle between data ops in there with file-based locking and all that odd stuff.

What would make this scheme sort of manageable from performance point is that for this purpose Java NIO has [ByteBuffer](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) which is a high level representation of low level byte mapping on disk.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at javolution.
They are using NIO direct buffers for data exchange.
In theory, this should be faster then plain JNI
since you do not have the overhead of passing
data through the argument list.