# Can a C library be loaded directly in Java without using JNI?

Tags: java, c, dll

I am new to  Java my project needs a C API calls called in JAVA file ,i tried with swig in Linux created shared library but i am facing issues there , any other way to call a C API in Java  dll directly loaded in any JAVA IDES tool, where it matches with function address called in Java and return the output as in C program does.conclusion load my C dll or library file in JAVA IDES and call the API from JAVA which are there in C lib.Direct function address matching and returning.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java C++ without JNI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035243/java-c-without-jni)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's [JNA](https://jna.java.net/) which is an alternative to JNI.